# How to set a good date with chart js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I make a graph with **NextJs** and **ChartJs** on the stats of the covid (over the last 30 days) that I get with an API that provides me with the date and the stats :

```
timeline: {
  cases: {
   '5/13/21': 5902343,
   '...' : ...
  },
}
```

I managed to make the graph but I would like to place the date returned for each stats on the X line of my label

I managed to do this code (lineData is't my request) :

```
labels: [Object.keys(lineData.timeline.cases)],
```

but it shows me all the dates as one and the same object.

For now my label looks like this

```
        labels: [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8",
          "9",
          "10",
          "11",
          "12",
          "13",
          "14",
          "15",
          "16",
          "17",
          "18",
          "19",
          "20",
          "21",
          "22",
          "23",
          "24",
          "25",
          "26",
          "27",
          "28",
          "29",
          "30",
        ],
```

and I would like to replace values with the one provided by the api

Comment: Show some more code. It is unclear what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array. So currently you have an array of array like:

```
labels: [ ['5/13/21'] ]
```

You can just do:

```
labels: Object.keys(lineData.timeline.cases) // labels: ['5/13/21']
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but let's say i want to put the days first because in the current design the api returns me MM / DD / YYYY
and I would like (if possible) DD / MM / YY How could I do that?

Comment: @DoctorPok you can use `.split('/')` on date key and rearrange the items in resulting array, then do `.join('/')` on it. Give it a try if you need a more detailed answer please post a separate question and share a link to it

Comment: okay so I post a new question, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951147/put-a-date-in-the-correct-order-from-a-json-file)