# Put a date in the correct order from a json file

Tags: javascript, next.js

I recover thanks to an API a json file made up like this :

```
timeline: {
  cases: {
   '5/13/21': 5902343,
   '...' : ...
  },
}
```

which then aims to constitute a chart with ChartJs

Except that in the json file the date and put in the format MM / DD / YY and I would like to change it to give DD / MM / YY

Comment: To convert date format ```let d=mm_dd_yyyy.split("/"); let dd_mm_yyyy = d[1]+"/"+d[0]+"/"+d[2];```

Comment: Or ```let d=mm_dd_yyyy.split("/"); let dd_mm_yyyy = [d[1],d[0],d[2]].join("/");```

Comment: ok, and I forgot to specify that the date was used for my labels function: which is defined like this (lineData is't my request) :

```labels: Object.keys(lineData.timeline.cases),```
so with your example how I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage array destructuring to achieve this:

```js
const labels = Object
  .keys(lineData.timeline.cases)
  .map((dateString) => {
    const [month, day, year] = dateString.split('/');
    return [day, month, year].join('/');
  });
```

```js
const lineData = {
  timeline: {
    cases: {
      '01/06/2015': 12345,
      '05/11/2012': 12345,
    }
  }
}

const labels = Object
  .keys(lineData.timeline.cases)
  .map((dateString) => {
    const [month, day, year] = dateString.split('/');
    return [day, month, year].join('/');
  });
  
console.log("BEFORE", Object.keys(lineData.timeline.cases));
console.log("AFTER", labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.map` method to create a new array with transformed items like:

```
labels: Object.keys(lineData.timeline.cases).map(day => {
    const dayArray = day.split('/');
    const month = dayArray.shift();
    return dayArray.splice(1, 0, month).join('/');
});
```

Or

```js
const dates = ['5/13/21', '6/16/21'].map(date => {
  const [month, day, year] = date.split('/');
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  // return [day, month, year].join('/'); Or this
});

console.log(dates);
```